# Select the closest item based on date?

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I have a collection of items, and i need to single out one item that has the closest date to the current date (in the future, not in the past). All this in xslt 1.0. Any suggestions to how this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

Brother, this is what you can do:

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
itemList = Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.GetDescendants().ToList<Item>();
itemList = itemList.OrderByDescending(c => c.Statistics.Created.Date).ToList<Item>();
```

Where itemList is obviously the list you want to sort.
Good luck!

And then i found out you're asking it to be XSL :):

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
<xsl:sort select="sc:fld(__created,.)" />
```

More reference [here at John West blog](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Working-with-Dates-Using-XSL-and-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx).

advise: The more complicated things you want to do in renderings the more you should consider to be using Sublayouts instead of XSL.

But good luck again!

Comment: I would also suggest you to use something else than xslt, it is slower than asp.net when the stuff you are doing is beyond simple data retrieval.